# Remote Access of MySQL Database from RaspberryPi with Python Connector

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to access a MySQL database stored on a windows machine remotely from a raspberry pi. The version of MySQL I am using is Server version: 8.0.19 MySQL Community Server - GPL. I have set up a user on the windows machine called 'RaspberryPi' and gave it access to the database 'database1'.

```
CREATE USER RaspberryPi@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database1.* TO RaspberryPi@'%';
```

I am using the python connector to interact with the database https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/

When running python scripts on the local windows machine it works fine however when trying to implement a remote connection it causes errors. The code I am running on the raspberry pi is shown below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error

def connect():
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=<IP_ADDRESS_OF_WINDOWS_MACHINE>,
            database='database1',
            user='RaspberryPi',
            password='password',
            port=3309
        )
        if conn.is_connected():
            print('Connected to MySQL database')
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        if conn is not None and conn.is_connected():
            print('Connection closed')
            conn.close()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    connect()
```

The result of the above code is:

```
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '<IP_ADDRESS_OF_WINDOWS_MACHINE>:3309' (110 Connection timed out)
```

I have read on other questions posted about changing the 'bind-address' [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)
however in my configuration file located under C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini there is no mention of a bind-address in this file.

I have also tried to connect to the database using the workbench on the windows machine but instead of giving it the default 127.0.0.1 hostname I gave it the  IP_ADDRESS_OF_WINDOWS_MACHINE  and it connected fine.

**EDIT**

Problem was on port number should be 3306 as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/6296759/nacho in comments. I am still unable to find the bind-address however in the configuration files for MySQL.

Comment: Are you sure this is ok port=3309?? The MySql standar port is 3306

Comment: Thank you I have been going crazy about what I've been doing wrong haha working now